# Google Cloud Long TTFB

Tags: performance, performance-tuning, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud seems to be having much longer TTFB than they specify in their documentation for cloud storage. You can see from [this WPT result](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151015_5N_ZYC/1/details/) that it varies from 500 to 700 MS.

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) says standard storage has TTFB typical of "tens of milliseconds"

Comment: I recommend to measure the TTFB of your website using your browser. You can refer tothis post for the steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731278/how-to-determine-time-to-first-byte

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Comment: Never figured it out. Probably related to network latency

Comment: Did you try the steps that Kamran recommended ? Also have you tried different network/location?

Comment: Your WPT results are no longer available on your provided link. In case you are looking to solve this issue, can you reproduce and share these tests again on your end?